# React modular styles not working with :hover::before, any solutions?

Tags: css, reactjs, module

When creating an animation on react, I used :hover::before, but due to the modularity of styles, it does not work

Here is a part of the styles from Header.module.scss

```css
.listItem::before {
    content: '';
    width: 0px;
    height: 3px;
    box-shadow: 3px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 0;
    transition: width .3s ease;
} 

.listItem:hover::before {
  width: 45px;
}
```

but for some reason the hover effect doesn't work
perhaps because react hashes modular styles

I hope for your help

Comment: Be sure your `.listItem` has `position:relative` and add `display:inline-block` to `.listItem:before`

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything works. For some reason I forgot about it, add position relative